# glReadPixels specify resolution

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am trying to capture a screenshot on iOS from an OpenGL view using `glReadPixels` at half of the native resolution.
`glReadPixels` is quite slow on retina screens so I'd like to somehow force reading every second pixel and every second row, resulting in a non-retina screenshot (1/4 of the resolution).

I tried setting these:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 2);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_ROWS, 2);
```

before calling `glReadPixels` but it doesn't seem to be changing absolutely anything. Instead, it just renders 1/4 of the original image because the width and height I'm passing to glReadPixels is the view's non-retina size.

Alternatively, if you know any more performant way of capturing an OpenGL screenshot, feel free to share it as well.

Comment: maybe set the lower res sooner by specifying a lower res render target (through the viewport)

Comment: Thanks, there are two problem with this approach:

- I want the live game image to be full retina resolution and only the screenshot to be 1x res. (for the described performance reasons)

- I am using SpriteKit, so I don't have explicit access to the render target's resolution other than the view itself. I will see what I can do with the view though...

Comment: What OpenGL version are you using? Looks like ES 3.0, since `GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS` is not available in ES 2.0?

Comment: Correct, ES 3.0. I am developing the app in Swift with SpriteKit for iOS 8+

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a very direct way of doing what you're looking for. As you already found out, `GL_PACK_SKIP_ROWS` and `GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS` do not have the functionality you intended. They only control how many rows/pixels are skipped at the start, not after each row/pixel. And I believe they control skipping in the destination memory anyway, not in the framebuffer you're reading from.

One simple approach to a partial solution would be to make a separate `glReadPixels()` call per row, which you can then make for every second row. You would still have to copy every second pixel from those rows, but at least it would cut the amount of data you read in half. And it does reduce the additional amount of memory to almost a quarter, since you would only store one row at full resolution. Of course you have overhead for making many more `glReadPixels()` calls, so it's hard to predict if this will be faster overall.

The nicer approach would be to produce a half-resolution frame that you can read directly. To do that, you could either:

- If your toolkits allow it, re-render the frame at half the resolution. You could use an FBO as render target for this, with half the size of the window.
- Copy the frame, while downscaling it in the process. Again, create an FBO with a render target half the size, and copy from default framebuffer to this FBO using `glBlitFramebuffer()`.

You can also look into making the read back asynchronous by using a pixel pack buffer (see `GL_PACK_BUFFER` argument to `glBindBuffer()`). This will most likely not make the operation faster, but it allows you to continue feeding commands to the GPU while you're waiting for the `glReadPixels()` results to arrive. It might help you take screenshots while being less disruptive to the game play.

Comment: This is helpful, trying.